# FileDialog in Qml not working in Release

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am working on project with `Qt Quick Control 2`. 
When I try to run my software in debug mode FileDialog.qml opens perfectly but when I deploy it as release mode it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4 
import QtQuick.Window 2.2 
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3 
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0 

// File Dialog to browse 
FileDialog { 
    id: openDialog 
    title: "Please Select An Image" 
    folder: shortcuts.pictures 
    nameFilters: ["Image files (*.BMP)"] 
    modality: Qt.NonModal 
    selectExisting: true 

    /*
     * do my stuff
    */
}
```

Comment: What does it mean that it does not work?

Comment: in fact it doesn't work in another PC. When I execute my release on My PC it works fine but in another Pc, it doesn't work

Comment: FileDialog is a type in QtQuick.Controls 1 version. Have you deployed the corresponding QML/Quick packages with your release binary along?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is my Js function that calls FileBrowse.qml (file in parameters).
I call this function in other view like this :

```
JsCommonCall.openFileDialog("frameFileBrowse.qml",2)


function openFileDialog(file,
                        parentCalled) {
    _component = Qt.createComponent(file);
    _popUp = _component.createObject(windowsMain,  {"x": offsetPopUpCreate,
                                                    "y": offsetPopUpCreate,
                                                    "parentCall":parentCalled});
    if(_popUp !== null)
        _popUp.open()
}
```

here it is my FileBrowse

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

// File Dialog to browse
FileDialog {
    id: openDialog
    title: "Please Select An Image"
    folder: shortcuts.home
    nameFilters: ["Image files (*.BMP)"]
    selectFolder: true 
    // variables 
    property int parentCall; 

    onAccepted: {
        imgCurrentCam1.source = openDialog.fileUrl;
        openDialog.close()
    }


    onRejected: {
        openDialog.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
FileDialog {
    id: fdExport
    title: qsTr("File name")
    folder: shortcuts.home
    selectFolder: true
    onAccepted: {

    }
}
```

and to run

```
    fdExport.open()
```

Please try to leave

```
modality: Qt.NonModal
```

from your code.

Comment: I try but it doesn't work. As I said before I think it is not the code but .dll problem, Because, When I deploy my software on another PC it doesn't work but in my Pc il works fine. Thx to give me your opinion

Comment: could someone help me ?

Comment: Ok, this is important to know.
Please have a look at how your are sharing your app.
When I release a Qml app for Windows I normally put the full Qml folder from Qt framework in the exe path.
Also I normally put all the Qt dlls in the exe path because it is not possible to know wich dlls will be used from the qml source code.
Finally bat very important is the qt.conf file.
Please try to add the full qml folder and all the dlls to your exe installation and then reply here how it is gone.

Comment: Hello, I put .exe of my apps in Qt framework (Qt/5.9/mingwXXX/bin) with all .dll and qt.conf and others .dll but it doesn't work in another PC.

Comment: Ok, at this point you should share or send to me a little project where there is the behaviour so I can verify and resolve.
Probably the resolution is under your eyes but a little bit hidden.

Comment: Oki. I will share it as soon as possible.

Comment: Hello ,sorry for  long time but in answer 2, you can see my code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which is the problem but the code below is perfectly portable on Windows machines. Tested in Linux too.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    FileDialog {
        id: fdImport
        title: qsTr("File name")
        folder: shortcuts.home
        onAccepted: {
            textEdit.text= fdImport.fileUrls[0]
        }
    }


    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle1
            color: "#ffffff"
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 8
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 8
            anchors.bottom: rectangle2.top
            anchors.bottomMargin: 6
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 8

            TextEdit {
                id: textEdit
                text: qsTr("Text Edit")
                anchors.fill: parent
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle2
            y: 441
            width: 128
            height: 32
            color: "#ffffff"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 8
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 7

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    fdImport.open()
                }

                Text {
                    id: text1
                    text: qsTr("Click me!")
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The qt.conf file

```
[Paths]
Plugins=plugins
Libraries=libs
```

Please remember to copy all the dll (release) in the executable folder, with the qml and plugins folders.

Comment: MODE DEBUG : message come from OUTPUT When I click on Browse button:  ------>>>>ShellStreams: AttachShellStreams: InitializedTrying to load localized resources for LANGID 1036 with Primary LANGID 12 code fr name French (Universal)Resource DLL loaded at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Internet Services\ShellStreams.resources\fr.lproj\ShellStreamsLocalized.dllNot running under explorer. Will not set thread locale11284 506C2510 ENTER: ShellStreamsFolder::ShellStreamsFolder
pidl = 1f50e04fd020ea3a6910a2d8802b30309d140 -> 2e80853fd6f0ec379740b3d61b4a891711800 ->

Answer (score 0):

One strange but possible reason for it is anti-virus: my FileDialog isn't opening either, and the entire QML application is hanging, while the AV is active.