# FileDialog is fine is debug mode, but not as expected in release mode

Tags: qt, qml, qfiledialog

A QML `FileDialog` to save a file works fine in debug mode.

[image: Screenshot: debug mode: fine]

The code is:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import Qt.labs.settings 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import Qt.labs.platform 1.0

Item {

    property string exportSceneName: "exported_scene"
    property url exportFolder: StandardPaths.writableLocation(StandardPaths.DocumentsLocation)

    signal  startExport()

    onStartExport: {
        runLogic()
    }

    function runLogic() {
        // ...
    }

    Button {
        onClicked: {
            fileDialog.open()
        }
    }
    
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        folder: exportFolder
        fileMode: FileDialog.SaveFile
        title: qsTr("Export Scene As STL")
        onAccepted: {
            exportFolder = folder
            var name = basename(file)
            exportSceneName = name
            startExport()
        }
    }

    function basename(str) {
        return (String(str).slice(String(str).lastIndexOf("/")+1))
    }

}
```

#### Release mode

Surprisingly, in release mode, the dialog is *open*-type rather than *save*-type:

[image: Screenshot: release mode: bad]

I have tried:

- Change the QML imports versions
- Clean the release build directory
- Modify `qtquickcontrols2.conf` file

However, none of them worked! I have studied similar posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49178542/3405291), but suggestions didn't work. What else can I try? Thanks.

### SOLUTION

Fixed by removing this import inside QML file:

```
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the issue is conflicting FileDialog definitions. Note that both imports `QtQuick.Dialogs` and `Qt.labs.platform` provide an object called `FileDialog`, but they do not use the same API. (There are several other objects like this in QML, and it's really annoying.) So it's probably trying to use one version of the dialog in debug mode, but for some reason choosing the other one in release mode.

The solution is to first of all make sure you remove any imports that you're not actually using. Then if you still need both, then you can label the imports:

```
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2 as QDiag
import Qt.labs.platform 1.0 as QPlat
```

Then when you create the `FileDialog`, you'll have to explicitly state which one you want to use.

```
QDiag.FileDialog {
}

QPlat.FileDialog {
}
```

Comment: Fixed by removing this import inside QML file: `import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2`

Comment: With your solution I got an error:
file:///D:/Qt5.12/5.12.10/mingw73_64/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:102:33: QML Settings: Failed to initialize QSettings instance. Status code is: 1
file:///D:/Qt5.12/5.12.10/mingw73_64/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:102:33: QML Settings: The following application identifiers have not been set: QVector("organizationName", "organizationDomain")

Comment: That warning has nothing to do with my solution. It's just saying that the FileDialog internally uses QSettings, which wants you to define an organization name and domain. Read the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) for more info. But I think your app will still work even if it shows that message.

Comment: Thank you. From the source code of DefaultFileDialog.qml it does use QSettings itself.